# Create a slanted-tab header in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, tabs, tabcontrol

I wanted to create a slanted tab header using the tabitem control in the silverlight toolkit. I want it to look like the image below but i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

[alt text http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1462/silverlighttabs.png](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1462/silverlighttabs.png)
http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1462/silverlighttabs.png

Any help and direction would be gladly appreciated

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search at SilverlightCream.com popped this one out:

http://antonidol.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/overlapping-tabitems-with-the-silverlight-toolkit-tabcontrol/

-Dave